# SQL Join returning wrong result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to join two tables. Table 1 is called account and it consists of account_id, fname, lname, picture and Table 2 is called friendpending and consists of account_id, friend_id and message. I'm making a program that allows users to add friends, when I pass in the account_id it returns that users name I need it to return the friend_id name.

This is what i have tried so far:

```
SELECT account.fname, account.lname, account.picture
from account
INNER JOIN friendpending ON account.account_id = friendpending.account_id
WHERE friendpending.account_id = p_account_id;
```

Comment: Is `p_account_id` a PHP variable? It should begin with a dollar sign but, preferably, should be provided as a parameter.

Comment: Also, why do you need the friendpending table if all the information you need is in the account table?

Comment: p_account_id is a parameter in mysql that is passed in i am doing this using stored procedures.

Comment: You aren't selecting any information from the friend's table, that is why it returns the user's details.

Comment: I am able to pass in the users ID and i am able to get it to return the friend_id's linked with the account_id but i am trying to link the tables so that the friend_id is displayed as their first name and last name. My mysql could be completely wrong i am quite new to it.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the friend's name from the friendpending table then you need to select that field (or fields):

```
SELECT friendpending.name, 
    account.fname, account.lname, account.picture 
FROM account INNER JOIN friendpending ON account.account_id = friendpending.account_id
WHERE friendpending.account_id = p_account_id;
```

or

```
SELECT friendpending.fname, friendpending.lname, account.picture  
FROM account INNER JOIN friendpending ON account.account_id = friendpending.account_id
WHERE friendpending.account_id = p_account_id;
```

---

Or, based on the comment below, `ON account.account_id = friendpending.friend_id`.

Comment: The friend pending table does not have a name column. I am trying to get the friend_id and match that with the account_id in the account table to get the name.

Comment: Currently you are matching account_id to account_id, so adjust your statement to match friend_id.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you are wanting to be returned needs to be included in the SELECT part of the query.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT friendpending.friend_id, 
friendpending.name, 
account.fname,
account.lname,
account.picture 
FROM account
INNER JOIN friendpending ON account.account_id = friendpending.account_id
WHERE friendpending.account_id = p_account_id;
```